# Green's Function of Higher Dimensions

Tags: differential-equations

Hello I am learning about Green's function as solutions to differential equations. I am curious about Mathematica's implementation of Green's function in dimensions larger than 3. Below is the code from Wolfram's documentation for the Green's function for the three dimensional Laplacian.

```
In[34]:= GreenFunction[-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] FullRegion[3], {0, 0, 0}]
```

This produces the correct solution of

```
Out[34]= 1/(4 \[Pi] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])
```

It seems like I can just add an extra dimension if I wanted to go higher in dimensions but this did not work. Does anyone have an explanation to why this does not work? I modified the code slightly thinking it would produce the Green's function for the four dimensional Laplacian, however what I did did not work, see below.

```
In[34]:= GreenFunction[-Laplacian[u[x, y, z, w], {x, y, z, w}], u[x, y, z, w], {x, y, z, w} \[Element] FullRegion[4], {0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

I can delete a dimension and Mathematica provides the appropriate solution.

```
In[34]:= GreenFunction[-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] FullRegion[2], {0, 0}]


Out[34]= -(Log[x^2 + y^2]/(4 \[Pi]))
```

Question: Why doesn't the code for Green's Function produce solutions in dimensions larger than 3? How would one go about finding Green's function using Mathematica in dimensions larger than 3?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This is an undocumented weakness in `GreenFunction`.

Comment: Even `GreenFunction[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, 
 u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 1}], {m, n,
   p}]` returns the input in 14.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Pretty lame that it doesn't work but thanks @user64494.